# Static property value is being reset

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm setting static property value in a method which is called when page loads but the value is still being reset. What may be the reason?

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page conroller="MyController" action="Init" >
//code here
</apex:page>
```

Apex Class:

```
public without sharing class MyController{
   private static Integer count{get;set;}
   public void Init(){
     count=10;
   }
   public void checkMethod(){
      System.debug('count: '+count);
   }
}
```

Output:

```
System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
```

count is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a request is made back to the server, Visualfoce automatically restores data members of the controller class via its [view state](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Visualforce_View_State) mechanism. But static variables are not included in that view state (which is not made explicit in the documentation).

In your example, when the page is first opened `count` will not be null because of your page action, but when submit mack to the controller it will be uninitialised and so null.

The quick fix for your case would be to remove the `static`.

With or without the `static`, you could also use this:

```
private static Integer count = 10;
```

or this lazy loading pattern that is useful when the initialisation is expensive and not always needed:

```
public static Integer count {
    get {
        if (count == null) count = 10;
        return count;
    }
    set;
}
```

Comment: When I try to remove static, it gives compiler error on saving the class -
The property Integer count is referenced by Visualforce Page in salesforce.com. Remove the usage and try again.

Comment: @SFDC The Apex/Visualforce consistency checking gets in the way sometimes. Either use a new name and then remove the old name or comment our the Visualforce page body, make the change and then uncomment the Visualforce page body.

Comment: Right.. I could save it now. I don't have static for the variable now but still returning null value. I'm using it in a selectList on VF page.
Updated code is:
    public string count{get {
        if (count == null) count = 'hi';
        return count;
    }
    set;
    }
VFpage:
    <apex:SelectList value="{!Count}" size="1">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!ListItem}"/>
    </apex:SelectList>

Answer (score 0):

It's resolved now. 
ActionFunction was getting called before selectList value is updated. Hence, I had to call apex:ActionFunction through JS and save value through **apex:param**.